# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-\tan^2(x)}\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-\tan^2(x)}\mathrm dx $$

$1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$

$u=\sqrt{2-\tan^2(x)}, dx={udu\over \sqrt{2-u}+(\sqrt{2-u^2})^3}$

$$\int_{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}/3}}^{\sqrt{2}}{udu\over \sqrt{2-u}+(\sqrt{2-u^2})^3}$$

Very messy, how do we evaluate this question in a easy manner?

Comment: Is there a [closed form representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan(sqrt(2-(tan(x))%5E2))+from+0+to+pi%2F6) of the answer?

Comment: @mickep. Could you, please, show what Mma produces ? I tried two different CAS for no answer.

Comment: The integral equals $\pi^2/20$. Google Sangchul Lee, *Some properties on generalized Ahmed’s integral*.

Answer (score 4):

Random integral, random substitution, no clue. That reminded me of something/someone. Anyway
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/6}\arctan\sqrt{2-\tan^2(x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{3}}\frac{\arctan\sqrt{2-u^2}}{1+u^2}\,du=\int_{\sqrt{5/3}}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{v\arctan(v)}{\sqrt{2-v^2}(3-v^2)}\,dv $$
can be tackled through Feynman's trick, since
$$ \int_{\sqrt{5/3}}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{v^2\,dv}{\sqrt{2-v^2}(3-v^2)(1+a^2 v^2)}=\int_{5/6}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{v}\,dv}{\sqrt{1-v}(3-2v)(1+ 2a^2 v)} $$
or
$$ \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{6}}\frac{2\sqrt{1-v^2}\,dv}{(1+2v^2)((1+ 2a^2)-2a^2 v^2)}$$
can be computed by partial fraction decomposition and the outcome can be integrated over $(0,1)$ with respect to $da$ through the dilogarithm machinery. The final outcome is indeed a $\frac{\pi^2}{20}$ and the original integral is pretty similar (and probably equivalent) to [Ahmed's integral](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5169). See also [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130208/absurd-integrals/2130278#2130278).

The integral can be written as
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{3\cos^2\theta-1}{\cos^2\theta}}\,d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1+3\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}\,d\theta$$
and directly evaluated through [Theorem 4.4](http://cfile29.uf.tistory.com/attach/226DBB4B529B6B73235C03) of [Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee). Credits to him.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What do you mean when you say that two integrals are equivalent? (That one of them is very easily converted into the other one by simple means?) 2) The link to "Theorem 4.4" is not working here, is it correctly written?

Comment: @mickep: 1) I mean that this integral and Ahmed's one can probably be shown to be a multiple one of the other, by non-trivial hypergeometric transformations 2) A https issue, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

We can *approximate* the value using composition of Taylor series for the integrand around $x=0$.

This would give
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2-\tan ^2(x)}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{x^2}{6 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{23 x^4}{144
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{3727 x^6}{25920 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{124627 x^8}{967680
   \sqrt{2}}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ Using the expansion to $O\left(x^{2n}\right)$ and computing the decimal representation of the result, we should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.494564 \\
 2 & 0.493675 \\
 3 & 0.493518 \\
 4 & 0.493488 \\
 5 & 0.493482 \\
 6 & 0.493481
\end{array}
\right)$$ quite close to the result from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: (there is a closed form : $\frac {\pi^2}{20}$ but pshht... :-))

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. I do respect the *pshht..* but I would really like to know more about it ! Cheers.

Comment: I don't have a proof but simply observed that the real part of the result will be $\,q(n)\pi^2\,$ with $q(n)$ rational for some upperbounds $\dfrac {\pi}n$ : $n=2\to q(2)=1/6,3\to 1/12,4\to 7/96,6\to 1/20,\cdots$